# How to make emacs completing-read display *Completions* buffer as soon as I type

Tags: emacs, completion

In emacs lisp, I expect the following to display a list of options in the completion buffer as I type. It prompts for information but doesn't display choices, either before or after I start typing. For example, I'd expect it to display 'First' after I'd typed 'F'.

```lisp
(defun reader ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((choices '("First" "Second" "Third")))
    (completing-read "Choose: " choices)))
```

Essentially I'm looking for something similar to the output described [here](https://howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/alt-completing-read.html). But what I get is this (there's nothing below the line, which is the edge of my window):

[image]

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong with `completing-read`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way `completing-read` behaves. You're not doing anything wrong. It just doesn't support any kind of automatic, incremental completion.

If you want such automatic completion then you either need to write your own code to provide that or use a completion framework that provides it.

[Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) was the first to provide this [incremental-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion#IncrementalCompletion) behavior. Many other packages now provide the same or similar.